# Getting an iframe and then access it as a document

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm having trouble accessing an iframe in order to manipulate content inside of the frame.

```
<iframe id="verify" src="http://www.wesite.com/"></iframe>
```

When I want to access it, with js, it tells me it's undefined

```
var frame = document.getElementById("verify");
```

If that were to work, how would I then access the stuff in that frame to manip it? Would it just be:

```
frame.document.getElementById("ElementInsideIframe").InnerHtml="etc";
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work check it:

```
  if ( frame.contentDocument ) {
    doc = objHTML.contentDocument;
  } else {
    doc = objHTML.contentWindow.document;
  }    
   doc .getElementById("ElementInsideIframe").InnerHtml="etc";
```

note: for cross domains this kind of JS will not work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below:

```
var temp = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
 var innerDoc = temp[0].contentDocument || temp[0].contentWindow.document;

 innerDoc.getElementById("ElementInsideIframe").innerHTML="Your Text";
```